# Would anything medically negative ever happen if I didn't scratch an itch?

Tags: risks, itching, scratch-scratching, tactile-touch

The title says it all - Would anything medically negative ever happen if I never scratched an itch? More specifically, one that does not stem from something like an insect, but is more of a self inflicted sensation.